# Accessing php array with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, mybb

To start off I apologize for the title as it may not be exactly what I'm trying to say, but it's the most relevant one I could think of.

I am running mybulletin board software and I am creating a custom page. I have a php array, and I want to print it based on **event.target.id**. Here is my code (cutting out irrelevant information):

```
<?php

$asd = array(1 => "");

$asd[1] = 1;

$template='<html>
<head>
{$headerinclude}

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$(".boxed").click(function(event) { //This is called, I just removed the .boxed code
alert(event.target.id); //This alerts 1
alert("{$asd[event.target.id]}"); //This should alert 1 but it doesnt

event.stopPropagation();//the code below does not matter just mybb things
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
{$header}

{$footer}

</body>
</html>';


$template=str_replace("\'", "'", addslashes($template));

add_breadcrumb($pages['name']);

eval("\$page=\"".$template."\";");
?>
```

I hope I am clear enough on what's my issue. Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: What is it alerting instead?

Comment: @OsmiumUSA The alert is just blank, nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a ] here: {$asd[event.target.id}

EDIT: that won't solve everything, indeed. What happens is that your event.target.id is only defined when the ".boxed" is clicked, but the PHP was already rendered and executed, so you won't have access to it like this again. So it won't work the way you want.
THe best option in this case is to make the PHP render a JS array inside the script.
Something like this: http://pastebin.com/UdyuG1js
This way you deal with a JS variable, not a PHP one.

Comment: I accidently deleted the ] when deleting other irrelevent code. I added it back but the issue is still the same.